# Index Match SumIF Problems

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, sumifs

I'm trying to create a formula that sums student attendance by week, based on the students ID number. Basically, I want it to look up the student ID, and then output the sum of attendance for certain weeks. This is what I came up with, but it's not working correctly. I'll also need this for each month.

```
=sumifs(index(Attendance!$A:$Z,MATCH('Attendance by Week'!A5,Attendance!$A:$A,0),0), Attendance!$F$6:$Z$6,Attendance!$F$4:$Z$4,">=" &'Attendance by Week'!F$4,Attendance!$F$4:$Z$4,"<"&'Attendance by Week'!F$4+7)
```

Attendance by Week Worksheet:
[image: Attendance by Week]
The dates are the start of the week (every Sunday)

Attendance Worksheet:
[image: Daily Attendance]
Each "1" means the student was present

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: I would consider adding a new row in `Attendance` with `=Weeknum()` for each date. Then do your lookup/sumif based on that instead of having to rely on funky date ranges.

Comment: This worked out! Thank you for a different approach!

Answer (score 0):

For this type of challenge I would skip formulas completely, and go with a PivotTable-based solution because not only do they aggregate things without the need for complex formulas but they also let you group things by numbers of days.

The only barrier you have is that your data is currently as a crosstab, and PivotTables don't like 'em. So you'd need to either change the data entry layout to a flat file i.e. this:

[image]

...or use one of the methods I outline at [convert cross table to list to make pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252860/convert-cross-table-to-list-to-make-pivot-table/47253398#47253398) to turn your crosstab into a flat file. (I used PowerQuery, which is built in to Excel 2016 or later and available as a free addin for Excel 2010 or 2013).

But once you've done that, you can then create a PivotTable that automatically does all that grouping and summing, like so:

[image]

...using the Grouping feature:

[image]